# This gray bar blocking my text box is driving me insane. It still comes up even after I turn off predictive text

Tags: ipad, keyboard, display

[image]

Anyone have any idea how to fix this? I have an attached keyboard case and whenever I try to use it, this gray bar just comes up and blocks the area where I am meant to see what it is that I am typing.

Answer (score 9):

To disable the bar completely, not just the predictive text suggestions, toggle "Shortcuts" in Settings > General > Keyboard. When it is disabled, the grey bar will not appear (whether or not your physical keyboard is connected).

[image: Keyboard settings]

Comment: Unfortunately this also disables any password managers used too… not a very good user experience. It’s the card/location entry bar that blocks content, not the Shortcuts bar (it’s a pity that only the top bar can’t be disabled).

Answer (score 2):

That bar is part of the QuickType predictive keyboard feature on iOS. To turn the feature off, go to `Settings` > `General` > `Keyboards`, scroll to the bottom, and turn `Predictive` off.

More information about QuickType is available in [this (slightly outdated, but still relevant) article](https://www.imore.com/how-use-quicktype-keyboard-iphone-and-ipad).

Comment: This doesn't solve the whole problem—as the (better) answer from Timothy points out, the `Shortcuts` option must also be disabled.